# "Integers mod n" with equations

Tags: group-theory

I have the following problem:

Find all solutions to the following equation on $\mathbb{Z}$17:

$x^2 + 1 = 0$

I don't know where to begin. I know the set goes from 0 to n-1, which is 16 in this example. But what then? Do I plug each of those 17 numbers into x and record the final values as solutions?

Answer (score 1):

That is certainly one approach.  With that few choices, just try them all and see which ones work.  A spreadsheet with copy down will make it easy, even up to a few thousand choices. You might know that $4^2=16,$ so $4^2+1 \equiv 0 \pmod {17}$, then recognize this implies $(-4)^2+1 \equiv 0 \pmod {17}$